# Opening files and changing file data to uppercase in C programming

Tags: c, file, scanf, fgets

I'am having some trouble with this code (see below). As regardless of what filename I enter, I get this gibberish " \330\370\277_\377 ". Can anyone tell me what I'am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    char line[81], filename[21];
    int i;
    FILE *inFile;
    printf("\nPlease enter the name of a file: ");
    gets(filename);
    inFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(inFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe file %s was not successfully opened.", filename);
        printf("\nPlease check that the specified file exists.");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(line, 81, inFile) != NULL) 
printf("\n%s\n", line);

for (i = 0; line[i]; ++i) {
    line[i] = toupper(line[i]);

}
    printf("\nPrinted in UPPER case: \n\n");
    rewind(inFile);
    printf("\n%s", line);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Error handling and code formatting :)

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("filename");
```

doesn't do what you hope. Look at the other scanf calls and the docs for clues. Here's an idea:

```
fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin);

for (i = strlen(filename); i>0; --i)
{
    switch(filename[i-1])
    {
        case '\n':
        case '\r': filename[i-1] = '\0';
                   continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: @The10thDoctor see my hint. Seems `fgets` doesn't do what you hope either :) Anyways, time to learn about the importance of _error handling_!

Comment: I tried it and keep getting "too many arguments" errors. It wont compile.

Comment: Well, it compiles with me. This is standard C :) http://codepad.org/crNGXgP6 or http://ideone.com/quxac2

Comment: Oh yes, it is.  But it keeps giving me an output that is not the text from the file im trying to open.

Comment: A live demo that shows it printing the text from `main.cpp` itself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b59be5239043656f3db385b5df01651a-c5e8e3d1e7bfc13a7e976835cefe5107 (**note**  that your loop is broken, but the other answer already points that out)

Comment: huh? What are you doing here?

Comment: @The10thDoctor Simple, you didn't supply an input file, right. Also, online compilers don't provide the option to store an input file. So, I picked main.cpp (because that's one file I _know_ was there). I don't mind if you don't follow, suffice it to say, I was demonstrating that my edit (a) compiled (b) worked. You could just... copy/paste/compare to find out what you did differently :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem to note is with the indentation causing miscommunication between you and the compiler.

```
while (fgets(line, 81, inFile) != NULL)
    printf("\n%s\n", line);
for(i = 0; line[i]; ++i)
{
    line[i] = toupper(line[i]);
}
```

This is why I recommend always using braces:

```
while (fgets(line, 81, inFile) != NULL) {
    printf("\n%s\n", line);

    for (i = 0; line[i]; ++i) {
        line[i] = toupper(line[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Print the filename to the console. Is it valid?

Comment: No, the usage of `toupper` is correct here.
The problem with the code in the question post is that you're only uppercase-ing the last line read from the file since you're doing it outside of the main loop that reads from that file.

Comment: I edited the code, getting rid of the brackets around the toupper portion to fix the problem.

Comment: Well, technically toupper takes an int, so you need the rather ugly cast `toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(line[i]))` to prevent unwanted sign extension...

Comment: Yeah, there's that. (How could I miss that >.<) --edit: Oh wait, C doesn't have `static_cast` :v